# How do I tell NoScript not to freak out when the Visual Studio help system calls up an MSDN web page in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, url, firefox-extensions

So, I'm merrily using Visual Studio 2010 Express and it's configured to get its help from the Web. I have some doubts on how some language feature works and I press F1 with the cursor on it. VS calls up an URL. This is what happens:

[image: NoScript complains]

In the NoScript console, this is what is logged:

```
[NoScript XSS] Sanitized suspicious request. Original URL [http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.DRAWING.GRAPHICS);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV3.5%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true] requested from [chrome://browser/content/browser.xul]. Sanitized URL: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%20SYSTEM.DRAWING.GRAPHICS%20%3Bk%20TargetFrameworkMoniker-%20.NETFRAMEWORK%2CVERSION%20V3.5%20%20%3Bk%20DevLang-CSHARP%20&rd=true#7978358773843752283].
```

But I know the request is legitimate, so I select "unsafe reload" (leaving, of course, the "ask next time" option checked!) and the correct page loads:

[image: The help I wanted]

Now, I can go through this every time I call the Visual Studio help, but really, I'd rather not. Is there any way I can add a smart whitelisting so such URLs go through? Or should I file a bug for the NoScript developers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this exclusion to the NoScript settings:

```
^https?://msdn\.microsoft\.com/query/dev10\.query\?[^'<>]+$
```

Comment: Sweet! that worked.

Comment: Tempted to register a dozen more accounts just to be able to upvote this answer more than once. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> But I know the request is legitimate, so I select "unsafe reload" (leaving, of course, the "ask next time" option checked!) and the correct page loads

Surely if you tell NoScript that you want to it to ask next time it will. You know the MSDN links are safe so clear this option next time and it should allow MSDN links through in future.